# Median of a frequency distribution table

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Is the median of a frequency distribution table independent of the scale taken?
If not,then why is it so?
My attempt:
I think that if the scale is modified ,still the median term remains the same as it is dependent on the number of terms , while not considering individual values

Comment: Which term is the middle one does not change if you multiply everything by a constant $k$, but the value of that term does change as it has been multiplied by $k$.  So the median is multiplied by $k$ on scaling

Comment: So if the terms were previously in cm..and now been converted to meter ...we consider it as a change in median value ,right ?

Comment: Yes: if you had three people with heights $155$cm, $176$cm and $183$cm then the median value would be $176$.  In metres the median of $1.55,1.76,1.83$ would be $1.76$.  Whether you see that as a change or not is more linguistics than mathematics